# Custom Authentication Filter for Mule Http Listener

Tags: spring, spring-security, mule

I would like to implement a Security Filter in Mule 3 extending OncePerRequestFilter from Spring Security. But I am unable to make it work because the code for authentication hadn't been reach.

Here is the code for registering the filter on mule xml.

```
 <spring:bean id="requestContextFilter" class="com.sample.authentication.BeforeBasicAuthFilter"/>

      <ss:http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
        <ss:custom-filter ref="requestContextFilter" before="FIRST"/>
     </ss:http>


   public class BeforeBasicAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

     private HttpServletRequest request;
     public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
       return request;
    }
    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
      this.request = request;
    }

   @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.request = request;
    System.out.println("XXXX ");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
   }

 }
```

I believe that that filter is not registered to be used by the http listener or authentication manager. Was there a way in Mule to register a filter to be used on a http Listener? My goal is that I should be able to intercept the raw http request before the authentication will take place.

Answer (score 0):

Use before `BASIC_AUTH_FILTER` in the `custom-filter`.

```
 <ss:http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <ss:custom-filter ref="requestContextFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
 </ss:http>
```

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that. My specific problem is implementing that filter on Mule http listener not a spring boot app.